# Site-to-Site VPN with Strongswan, DNS server, overlapping subnets)

Tags: dns, vpn, nat, ipsec, strongswan

I need to create a `site-to-site` VPN with a remote VPC (IKEv2 + IPSec). Both sides use some web resources of the other, those services hostnames are mapped to IPs using a DNS server (one on each side). Side A uses `Fortigate`, Side B uses `StrongSwan`.

The network looks as follow, where `Side B` has access to `subnets A1, A2, A3`, while `Side A` has access to `subnet B`:

[image: setup 1]

This is the configuration I'm using on Side B

```
/etc/ipsec.config

conn %default
  keyexchange=ikev2
  mobike=no
  authby=psk

conn sideA
  left=%defaultroute
  leftid=GATEWAY_B_PUBLIC_IP
  leftsubnet=SUBNET_B
  right=GATEWAY_A_PUBLIC_IP
  rightid=GATEWAY_A_PRIVATE_IP
  rightsubnet=SUBNET_A1,SUBNET_A2,SUBNET_A3
  type=tunnel
  auto=start
```

The issue is that `Subnet A4` overlaps `Subnet B`, so this configuration doesn't work.
`VPN Gateway B` is a virtual machine running Ubuntu 20, so it's open to customizations.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I've changed the `ipsec.conf` as per following

```
conn %default
  keyexchange=ikev2
  mobike=no
  authby=psk

conn sideA
  left=%defaultroute
  leftid=GATEWAY_B_PUBLIC_IP
  leftsubnet=VIRTUAL_SUBNET_B
  right=GATEWAY_A_PUBLIC_IP
  rightid=GATEWAY_A_PRIVATE_IP
  rightsubnet=SUBNET_A1,SUBNET_A2,SUBNET_A3
  type=tunnel
  auto=start
```

Where the `VIRTUAL_SUBNET_B` is a virtual subnet that doesn't overlap either with the left or the right side.

and created the following **NAT** rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s SUBNET_Ax -d VIRTUAL_SUBNET_B -j NETMAP --to SUBNET_B
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s SUBNET_B -d SUBNET_Ax -j NETMAP --to VIRTUAL_SUBNET_B
```

adding the following lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
```

Comment: How did you created the virtual subnet ?